# What does this mean in the WordPress Menu Code

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I was hoping someone could explain to me what the "%1$s, %2$s, %3$s" characters mean in the WordPress navigation menu function as found below:

```
$defaults = array( 'menu' => '', 'container' => 'div', 'container_class' => '', 'container_id' => '', 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'menu_id' => '',
    'echo' => true, 'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu', 'before' => '', 'after' => '', 'link_before' => '', 'link_after' => '', 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth' => 0, 'walker' => '', 'theme_location' => '' );
```

Thank you in advance,

T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$items_wrap**

(string) (optional) Evaluated as the format string argument of a sprintf() expression. The format string incorporates the other parameters by numbered token. %1$s is expanded to the value of the 'menu_id' parameter, %2$s is expanded to the value of the 'menu_class' parameter, and %3$s is expanded to the value of the list items. If a numbered token is omitted from the format string, the related parameter is omitted from the menu markup.
Default: %3$s

Source : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu